# Solr Result Ranking modifications to a particlar query

Tags: solr

I am newbie to Solr and I am trying to build a simple search solution for my website. I am trying to build a feature which is similar to Swifttype's result ranking feature. 
i.e., Lets say "ice" results in

1. Ice
2. Iceberg
3. Ice cream
4. ......

so on....

If i want to rank "Ice cream" higher only for query "ice", but when i search for other search terms like "Iceland" default ranking should be maintained. how can i achieve that?

I am using solr v7.5

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Query Elevation Component](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/the-query-elevation-component.html) lets you configure the top results for a given query regardless of the normal Lucene scoring.

More importantly, you will need to configure elevate.xml file which looks like this:

```
<elevate>
  <query text="ice">
    <doc id="1" /> //where id=1 is your ice cream document
    <doc id="2" />
    <doc id="3" />
  </query>

</elevate>
```

Later, during searches you only need to enable it by specifying http param `enableElevation=true`

Comment: Theoretically this seems to be a good solution. Will try this!! Thanks for the reply...